# Parse Query Not Returning Full Object Details

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am working on a messaging app with iOS and Parse and am having trouble with Parse queries returning object with missing parameters.  Let me explain.

I have created custom user objects.  The user objects called MessageUserPFObjects have a pointer field that points to a PFUser.

I also have custom message object called MessagePFObjects.  The MessagePFObject has a pointer field that points to the message sender and message receiver.  Both the message sender and receiver are MessageUserPFObjects.

I am creating PFUsers, MessageUserPFObjects and MessagePFObjects in Parse without any trouble.  I can see all of the fields are populated in Core.

My problem comes when I query the MessagePFObjects.  I am querying for any message that have a specific MessageUserPFObject as the message sender or receiver.  I am returned all of the MessagePFObjects but the MessageUserPFObject for the message receiver does not have any of the properties.  Here is the query, and the resulting print statement.

// Note self.currentMessageUser is a MessageUserPFObject

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "messageSender == %@ OR messageReceiver == %@", self.currentMessageUser!, self.currentMessageUser!)

let query = MessagePFObject.queryWithPredicate(predicate)

query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (result, error) -> Void in

    if result!.count > 0
    {
        for element in result!
        {
            let tempMessage = element as! MessagePFObject
            print("I am printing the messageSender returned from Parse \(tempMessage.messageSender)")
            print("I am printing the messageReceiver returned from Parse \(tempMessage.messageReceiver)")
        }
}
```

Print Results

> I am printing the messageSender returned from Parse
>    {    accountClaimed = 1;
>       firstName = Tom;
>       lastName = Hanson;
>       numberOfMessagesReceived = 0;
>       numberOfMessagesSent = 0;    messageUser = ""; }
>
> I am printing the messageReceiver returned from Parse
>    { }

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your query to make sure that the user objects are included in the fetch from Parse

```
query.includeKey("messageSender")
query.includeKey("messageReceiver")
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you kindly.